# Image failing to display while other images do in the HTML editor

Tags: image, tags, href

I have been having some issues getting some picture files to display in a very basic html file.

So I reverted to a simple html page with 5 or so images some I have control over and some that I randomly found online. To which the results vary widely.

Oddly one photo I found online works with everything, another only partly and others nothing.

I used the old HTML editor to see if they would display and like I mentioned above some do and some do not, I am not fully sure why this is.

I would like to find the reason behind this as it's not SSL from what I can make out, I've also force uploaded in binary on my images and still same result.

Front Page 2003
Microsoft Expression Web 4 (Still available for free download from microsoft)

I understand these editors are retired however they do both display the one image which works exactly as it should but I cannot understand the reason why that's behind this.

The code below is "cat-fish". The cat can be viewed in all modes, while the fish is limited only in preview mode and not design, yet the cat is viewed as it should. I have tried other links where the image cannot be seen in any mode.

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>New Page 1</title>
</head>

<body>

<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">


<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQD4ye4nFpfjfN_epetQ_HWUht5M2Zm08VO9A&usqp=CAU">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So, you're basically asking "Why something doesn't work somewhere sometimes?" I doubt anyone can answer anything without an exact case they can reproduce, or at least include the code you have.

Comment: I have added the HTML code links so you can add the code to the editors and see it's display.